# Обвертка над итератором для преобразования типа

Tags: c++, stl, boost, итераторы

Есть два типа A и B, между объектами этих типов установлено соответствие. Есть набор X значений типа А и итератор по этому набору. Необходимо с минимальными трудозатратами на основе итератора X получить итератор по значениям типа B.

В общем по-простому говоря, есть контейнер типа A, из итератора А нужно получить итератор B, потому что клиент принимает итераторы B.

Например:

```
typedef std::pair<int, float> A;
typedef float                 B;

B A2B(const A & item) // соответствие между A и B
{
    return item.second;
}

std::vector<A> X;
input_iterator<B> bi = magic_iterator_wrapper(A2B, X.begin());
```

Чем может быть `magic_iterator_wrapper`?

Comment: Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, каждый объект типа А знает об объекте типа И. Но не совсем понятно, каким образом _набор_ объектов типа A узнает о _наборе_ объектов типа B. Например, если первому объекту из набора А соответствует последний объект из набора В. Или вам нужен итератор по виртуальному, несуществующему в реальности набору В?

Comment: @VladD Да вы правильно поняли. По-простому говоря, есть контейнер типа A, из итератора А нужно пуличить итератор B потому что клиент принимает итераторы B. Я наврено вопрос сформулировал слишком вычурно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

using A = std::pair<int, float>;
using B = float;

float A2B(const A & item)
{
    return item.second;
}

template<typename I, typename F>
auto make_transform_iterator(I i, F f) {
    return boost::transform_iterator<F, I>{i, f};
}

int main() {
    std::vector<A> v = {{0, 1}, {0, 20}};

    auto first = make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), A2B);
    auto last = make_transform_iterator(v.end(), A2B);

    std::cout << std::accumulate(first, last, 0) << '\n';
}
```

[>>> То же на реальном компиляторе <<<](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa972258d448b80e)

Comment: Я его первым делом попытался применить, но он не допускает чтобы результирующий тип был отличным от исходного. Асертами ругается. Вот http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html#id3

Comment: Раз так, может, имеет смысл помериться версиями буста?

Comment: Мерятся не надо, просто я его не умел готовить. Все работает.